# how to pre-configure an elasticsearch pipeline in docker image?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch image that is being used as a base image for multiple containers. I am wondering if there is any way to pre-configure an ingest pipeline such that the process of creating the image  and building a container also creates the pipeline for me? It'd be great if the base image comes with the pipeline that i want it to have, otherwise I'd have to docker exec into each container that uses this image and send a curl request in each one to create the pipeline.

Right now I'm thinking that I have to add a curl to the elasticsearch server (after it starts) in docker-entrypoint.sh, but i'm not sure if there's any other way

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to use docker-compose. I personally find it very convenient. With one file you can configure a whole stack.

Here is an example to help you start:

```
 version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - node.name=node-test1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - node-test1data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - node.name=node-test2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - node-test2data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
       - elasticsearch
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.2
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
```

Comment: apologies for my lack of docker experience but where in the docker-compose would i put the pipeline definition for elasticsearch?

Comment: No problem, you should put the pipeline definition in `logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf`. Then map the volume to the docker container as you can see above in the logstash volumes section of the docker-compose.

Comment: What if we don't want to use logstash, but directly use ingest node of elastic search. How would we configure then?